# init: /etc/init.conf: Unable to load configuration: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, virtualization

Running Linux 6 on VMWare, I noticed this in the system message log:

> init: /etc/init.conf: Unable to load configuration: No such file or directory

What's the cause of this error? How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in upstart, it is just log noise.

Comment: @slm Formally this does not answer the question as it is worded, indeed. But from its content it's rather an answer than a comment. I suggest against deleting.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. Perhaps you could expand this "answer" it's a little light on details.